# PHP Stop Word List

Tags: php, arrays, performance, words

I'm playing about with a stop words within my code I have an array full of words that I'd like to check, and an array of words I want to check against.

At the moment I'm looping through the array one at at a time and removing the word if its in_array vs the stop word list but I wonder if there's a better way of doing it, I've looked at array_diff and such however if I have multiple stop words in the first array, array_diff only appears to remove the first occurrence.

The focus is on speed and memory usage but speed more so.

Edit -

The first array is singular words, based on blog comments (these are usually quite long) the second array is singular words of stop words. Sorry for not making that clear

Thanks

Comment: Is the data you are trying to check at any point going to enter a database? mySQL has great and fast full text searching abilities.

Comment: No, unless we have an sqlite db but no mySQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Using str_replace...

A simple approach is to use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) or [str_ireplace](http://php.net/str_replace), which can take an array of 'needles' (things to search for), corresponding replacements, and an array of 'haystacks' (things to operate on).

```
$haystacks=array(
  "The quick brown fox",
  "jumps over the ",
  "lazy dog"
);

$needles=array(
  "the", "lazy", "quick"
);

$result=str_ireplace($needles, "", $haystacks);

var_dump($result);
```

This produces

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "  brown fox"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "jumps over  "
  [2]=>
  string(4) " dog"
}
```

As an aside, a quick way to clean up the trailing spaces this leaves would be to use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to call [trim](http://php.net/trim) for each element

```
$result=array_map("trim", $result);
```

The drawback of using str_replace is that it will replace matches found *within* words, rather than just whole words. To address that, we can use regular expressions...

## Use preg_replace

An approach using [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) looks very similar to the above, but the needles are regular expressions, and we check for a 'word boundary' at the start and end of the match using \b

```
$haystacks=array(
"For we shall use fortran to",
"fortify the general theme",
"of this torrent of nonsense"
);

$needles=array(
  '/\bfor\b/i', 
  '/\bthe\b/i', 
  '/\bto\b/i', 
  '/\bof\b/i'
);

$result=preg_replace($needles, "", $haystacks);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll look into that and see if I can get that working but I've updated the question, the $haystacks array I have is only full of singular words not sentances

Comment: A quick check shows that this does what it says on the tin however, if I have for on my stop word list, it removes it from everything including words such as fortran, fort and such.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to use preg_replace

Comment: @PaulDixon  I'd remove the str_replace example if you have a second.. for anything other than very specific word collections it will fail every time as a proper English stop words list is going to include things like "a" and "at" which will damage other valid words.

Comment: Both elements of the answer might help someone, and it's not that long a read :)

Answer (score 2):

array_diff() should work.

```
$sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps the fence and runs";
$array = explode(" ", $sentence);
$stopwords = array("the","and","an","of");

print_r(array_diff($array,$stopwords));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [1] => quick
    [2] => brown
    [3] => fox
    [4] => jumps
    [6] => fence
    [8] => runs
)
```

I tested on this site: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you already have two sorted arrays, you can use this algorithm to remove each element from array A that is also in array B (in mathematical terms: A \ B):

```
for ($i=0, $n=count($a), $j=0, $m=count($b); $i<$n && $j<$m; ) {
    $diff = strcmp($a[$i], $b[$j]);
    if ($diff == 0) {
        unset($a[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
    if ($diff < 0) {
        $i++;
    }
    if ($diff > 0) {
        $j++;
    }
}
```

This does only require O(*n*) steps.

Another approach would be to use the words of array B as keys for an index (using [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip)), iterate the values of A and see if they are a key in the index using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists):

```
$index = array_flip($b);
foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if (array_key_exists($val, $b)) {
        unset($a[$key]);
    }
}
```

Again, this is O(*n*) as it avoids looking up each value in B for each value in A that would be O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score -1):

what about using in_array

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

The function accepts a needle that is an array.

bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict ] )

alternatively you could loop through your stop words one by one, and find all the matches