# Extract Relevant Tag/Keywords from Text block

Tags: php, javascript, tags, stop-words

I wanted a particular implementation, such that the user provide a block of text like:

> "Requirements
>   - Working knowledge, on LAMP Environment using Linux, Apache 2,
>   MySQL 5 and PHP 5,
>   - Knowledge of Web 2.0 Standards
>   - Comfortable with JSON
>   - Hands on Experience on working with Frameworks, Zend, OOPs
>   - Cross Browser Javascripting, JQuery etc.
>   - Knowledge of Version Control Software such as sub-version will be
>   preferable."

What I want to do is automatically select relevant keywords and create tags/keywords, hence for the above piece of text, relevant tags should be: **mysql, php, json, jquery, version control, oop, web2.0, javascript**

How can I go about doing it in PHP/Javascript etc? A headstart would be really helpful.

Answer (score 21):

A very naive method is to remove common [stopwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752896/php-stop-word-list) from the text, leaving you with more meaningful words like 'Standards', 'JSON', etc. You will still get a lot of noise however, so you may consider a service like [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/) which can do a rather sophisticated analysis of your text.

**Update:**

Okay, the link in my previous answer pointed to implementations, but you asked for one so a simple one is here:

```
function stopWords($text, $stopwords) {

  // Remove line breaks and spaces from stopwords
    $stopwords = array_map(function($x){return trim(strtolower($x));}, $stopwords);

  // Replace all non-word chars with comma
  $pattern = '/[0-9\W]/';
  $text = preg_replace($pattern, ',', $text);

  // Create an array from $text
  $text_array = explode(",",$text);

  // remove whitespace and lowercase words in $text
  $text_array = array_map(function($x){return trim(strtolower($x));}, $text_array);

  foreach ($text_array as $term) {
    if (!in_array($term, $stopwords)) {
      $keywords[] = $term;
    }
  };

  return array_filter($keywords);
}

$stopwords = file('stop_words.txt');
$text = "Requirements - Working knowledge, on LAMP Environment using Linux, Apache 2, MySQL 5 and PHP 5, - Knowledge of Web 2.0 Standards - Comfortable with JSON - Hands on Experience on working with Frameworks, Zend, OOPs - Cross Browser Javascripting, JQuery etc. - Knowledge of Version Control Software such as sub-version will be preferable.";

print_r(stopWords($text, $stopwords));
```

You can see this, and the contents of `stop_word.txt` in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/802249).

Running the above on your example text produces the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => requirements
    [4] => linux
    [6] => apache
    [10] => mysql
    [13] => php
    [25] => json
    [28] => frameworks
    [30] => zend
    [34] => browser
    [35] => javascripting
    [37] => jquery
    [38] => etc
    [42] => software
    [43] => preferable
)
```

So, like I said, this is somewhat naive and could use more optimization (plus it's slow) but it does pull out the more relevant keywords from your text. You would need to do some fine tuning on the stop words as well. Capturing terms like `Web 2.0` will be very difficult, so again I think you would be better off using a serious service like OpenCalais which can understand a text and return a list of entities and references. [DocumentCloud](http://www.documentcloud.org/home) relies on this very service to gather information from documents.

Also, for client side implementation you could do pretty much the same thing with JavaScript, and probably much cleaner (although it could be slow for the client.)

Comment: Thanks Darren. It naive indeed, but very exhaustive, can you recommend an implementation, ie use preg_replace sort of thing or some efficient matching script?

Comment: Great! Thanks for the implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: His homework is what I am interested in. And your answer is excellent. Open calais look good but english ONLY !! Voted up 4u

Answer (score 5):

I did a quick review of these this morning and to my surprise one which performs best with my test phrase was written in PHP

- http://code.fivefilters.org/term-extraction
- demo: http://fivefilters.org/term-extraction/

What looked like the most professional one performed abysmally: viewer.opencalais.com

Others that were OK were (not sure what language they're written in)

- www.nactem.ac.uk/software/termine/#form
- www.alchemyapi.com/api/keyword/

Comment: unfortunately the link to the code no longer works and it seems the code is paid. I managed to find out it's based on top of a PHP port of Topia's Term Extractor:  https://bitbucket.org/fivefilters/term-extraction/src/master/

Answer (score 2):

This is not easy to do because it requires some type of fuzzy logic. You should use the Yahoo Term extractor YQL

Check it out: [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20search.termextract%20where%20context=%22Italian%20sculptors%20and%20painters%20of%20the%20renaissance%20favored%20the%20Virgin%20Mary%20for%20inspiration%22)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am looking for something like this. I tried YQL but somehow it did not recognize a lot of terms. Found this site called Zemanta which is kinda good, I'm planning on using both and merging my results.

Comment: this is the most awesome thing i have found on internet in like 5 years or so...... thanks

Comment: link is dead unfortunately, looks like Yahoo scrapped the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to show the client keywords/tags or whether you want to extract the keywords / tags from the block of text then do further computation with them.

If you only need to show them then clientside handling is fine. If you need them for further computation then use serverside handling for it.

I can recommend a javascript clientside implementation if you can supply some more details. If you want to generically "know" the keywords then some kind of clever solution is neccesary

If you have a list of keywords then you can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to extract the data

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you recommend a clientside implementaion? What I want is, when a user fills a block of text, it should extract relevant tags out of it.